# Values of Bernoulli polynomials at roots of unity

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, bernoulli-numbers

I am wondering if there are any nice results on the values of Bernoulli polynomials at roots of unity, besides those at 1 or -1.

Comment: Also posted to stackoverflow, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36519927/values-of-bernoulli-polynomials-at-roots-of-unity

Comment: Changing a single letter in a misspelled word seems like a pretty trivial edit to make considering this bumps the question to the front page. Not a big deal in isolation I suppose.